# How to set an "Accept:" header on Spring RestTemplate request?

Tags: spring, rest, resttemplate

I want to set the value of the `Accept:` in a request I am making using Spring's `RestTemplate`.

Here is my Spring request handling code

```
@RequestMapping(
    value= "/uom_matrix_save_or_edit", 
    method = RequestMethod.POST,
    produces="application/json"
)
public @ResponseBody ModelMap uomMatrixSaveOrEdit(
    ModelMap model,
    @RequestParam("parentId") String parentId
){
    model.addAttribute("attributeValues",parentId);
    return model;
}
```

and here is my Java REST client:

```
public void post(){
    MultiValueMap<String, String> params = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
    params.add("parentId", "parentId");
    String result = rest.postForObject( url, params, String.class) ;
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

This works for me; I get a JSON string from the server side.

My question is: how can I specify the `Accept:` header (e.g. `application/json`,`application/xml`, ... ) and request method (e.g. `GET`,`POST`, ... ) when I use RestTemplate?

Answer (score 481, accepted):

I suggest using one of the [`exchange`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#exchange%28java.lang.String,%20org.springframework.http.HttpMethod,%20org.springframework.http.HttpEntity,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object...%29) methods that accepts an [`HttpEntity`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpEntity.html) for which you can also set the [`HttpHeaders`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders.html). (You can also specify the HTTP method you want to use.)

For example,

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>("body", headers);

restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
```

I prefer this solution because it's strongly typed, ie. `exchange` expects an `HttpEntity`.

However, you can also pass that `HttpEntity` as a `request` argument to `postForObject`.

```
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>("body", headers);
restTemplate.postForObject(url, entity, String.class);
```

This is mentioned in the [`RestTemplate#postForObject` Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#postForObject-java.net.URI-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Class-).

> The `request` parameter can be a `HttpEntity` in order to **add additional
> HTTP headers to the request**.

Answer (score 157):

You could set an interceptor "ClientHttpRequestInterceptor" in your RestTemplate to avoid setting the header every time you send a request.

```
public class HeaderRequestInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

        private final String headerName;

        private final String headerValue;

        public HeaderRequestInterceptor(String headerName, String headerValue) {
            this.headerName = headerName;
            this.headerValue = headerValue;
        }

        @Override
        public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
            request.getHeaders().set(headerName, headerValue);
            return execution.execute(request, body);
        }
    }
```

Then

```
List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = new ArrayList<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor>();
interceptors.add(new HeaderRequestInterceptor("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE));

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.setInterceptors(interceptors);
```

Comment: Spring Boot 1.3 has a HttpHeaderInterceptor, so we don't need to create our own implementation of ClientHttpRequestInterceptor.

Comment: For some reason, HttpHeaderInterceptor is only in spring-boot-devtools. So we still have to implement ClientHttpRequestInterceptor ourselves. I think it should be moved into spring-web.

Comment: Is it better to add default headers to ClientHttpRequestFactory set to the rest template instead of adding interceptors? P.S. you should add your answer in a separate question since this deals with default headers. Had to look for a while to reach here!

Comment: if there are two services that use two diff id /pass that we have to call, this interceptor at resttemplate level is too high level right? you need this at request level - generally RestTemplate is a @Bean in spring boot config

Answer (score 37):

If, like me, you struggled to find an example that uses headers with basic authentication and the rest template exchange API, this is what I finally worked out...

```
private HttpHeaders createHttpHeaders(String user, String password)
{
    String notEncoded = user + ":" + password;
    String encodedAuth = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(notEncoded.getBytes());
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedAuth);
    return headers;
}

private void doYourThing() 
{
    String theUrl = "http://blah.blah.com:8080/rest/api/blah";
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    try {
        HttpHeaders headers = createHttpHeaders("fred","1234");
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters", headers);
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(theUrl, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
        System.out.println("Result - status ("+ response.getStatusCode() + ") has body: " + response.hasBody());
    }
    catch (Exception eek) {
        System.out.println("** Exception: "+ eek.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 20):

#### Calling a RESTful API using RestTemplate

Example 1:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
// Add the Jackson message converter
restTemplate.getMessageConverters()
                .add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
headers.set("Authorization", "Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=");
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters", headers);
restTemplate.getInterceptors()
                .add(new BasicAuthorizationInterceptor(USERID, PWORD));
String requestJson = getRequetJson(Code, emailAddr, firstName, lastName);
response = restTemplate.postForObject(URL, requestJson, MYObject.class);
```

Example 2:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String requestJson = getRequetJson(code, emil, name, lastName);
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
String userPass = USERID + ":" + PWORD;
String authHeader =
    "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(userPass.getBytes());
headers.set(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authHeader);
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(requestJson, headers);
ResponseEntity<MyObject> responseEntity;
responseEntity =
    this.restTemplate.exchange(URI, HttpMethod.POST, request, Object.class);
responseEntity.getBody()
```

The `getRequestJson` method creates a JSON Object:

```
private String getRequetJson(String Code, String emailAddr, String name) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode rootNode = mapper.createObjectNode();
    ((ObjectNode) rootNode).put("code", Code);
    ((ObjectNode) rootNode).put("email", emailAdd);
    ((ObjectNode) rootNode).put("firstName", name);
    String jsonString = null;
    try {
        jsonString = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
                               .writeValueAsString(rootNode);
    }
    catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return jsonString;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Short solution without `HttpHeaders` creating:

```
RequestEntity<Void> request = RequestEntity.post(URI.create(url))
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                // any other headers
                .header("PRIVATE-TOKEN", "token")
                .build();

ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(request, String.class);
return response.getBody();
```

UPDATE: but in case specific headers `HttpHeaders` become simple:

```
RequestEntity.post(URI.create(AMOCRM_URL + url))
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .headers(
                    new HttpHeaders() {{
                        setBearerAuth(getAccessToken());
                    }})
            .body(...)
```

Comment: I do not understand why adding working headers in your local environment needs to be such a PIA, this, like all other methods I've seen on the web just doesn't work...

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple answer. Hope it helps someone.

```
import org.springframework.boot.devtools.remote.client.HttpHeaderInterceptor;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequestInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;


public String post(SomeRequest someRequest) {
    // create a list the headers 
    List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = new ArrayList<>();
    interceptors.add(new HttpHeaderInterceptor("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE));
    interceptors.add(new HttpHeaderInterceptor("ContentType", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE));
    interceptors.add(new HttpHeaderInterceptor("username", "user123"));
    interceptors.add(new HttpHeaderInterceptor("customHeader1", "c1"));
    interceptors.add(new HttpHeaderInterceptor("customHeader2", "c2"));
    // initialize RestTemplate
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    // set header interceptors here
    restTemplate.setInterceptors(interceptors);
    // post the request. The response should be JSON string
    String response = restTemplate.postForObject(Url, someRequest, String.class);
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Your code will use Spring Devtools as a production dependency (by importing  org.springframework.boot.devtools.remote.client.HttpHeaderInterceptor)...