# Integration testing spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, junit, integration-testing

I'm trying to test my spring boot application.I'm doing integration testing but my test keeps on failing as the response returned by url cannot be jsonfied.please Help. 
Here is the test function:

```
@Test
    public void testRetrieveStudentCourse() throws JSONException {

    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(null, headers);

    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
            createURLWithPort("/student/getdetails/id"),
            HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);

    String expected = "{\"id\":1,\"rollno\":\"2\",\"Address\":\"Chicago\"}";

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response.getBody());

        JSONAssert.assertEquals(expected, json, false);

}
```

Error:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:159)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:172)
    at testRetrieveStudentCourse(StudentControllerIT.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a IT test as below.

```
  @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class JmStudentServiceApplicationTests {

   @Autowired
   private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

   @Autowired
   private StudentRepository studentRepository;

   @Test
   public void test() {

      Student student = new Student();
      student.setId("1");
      student.setName("Test Student");

      studentRepository.createStudent(student);

      assertThat(studentRepository.getStudentById("1").getName().equals("Test Student"));
      ResponseEntity<Student> responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity("/students/by-id/{id}",Student.class,"1");
      assertThat(responseEntity.getBody().getName().equals("Test Student"));

   }

}
```

This link [IT test](http://www.kaushikbaruah.com/posts/integration-test-with-spring-boot/) explains this in detail.

Answer (score 0):

You receive an XML response. Therefore you cannot create a `JSONObject` from this response.

Please look at [Why RestTemplate GET response is in JSON when should be in XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21613416/why-resttemplate-get-response-is-in-json-when-should-be-in-xml) for more information about how to get a JSON response.