# How to proxy/mirror a Websocket connection url in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets, websocket, spring-rest

I've almost completed [How can I embed a server-side Shiny app into a JSP page without exposing the app elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52601075/how-can-i-embed-a-server-side-shiny-app-into-a-jsp-page-without-exposing-the-app), but the final part of this solution avenue has me really stuck.

(Basic background: this is a Spring MVC Java webserver, on the same machine as a Shiny app. I'd like to avoid moving to Spring Boot if possible.)

The code is successfully mirroring all the Shiny content from `localhost:3305` on to `localhost:8080/project/shiny-proxy`, EXCEPT for a websocket connection URL: `ws://localhost:8080/project/shiny-proxy/websocket/` needs to map to `ws://localhost:3305/websocket/`. `http://localhost:3305/websocket/` returns a hard-coded "Not found" HTML page when I visit it in Chrome, so requesting using the `http://` prefix isn't likely to work via any method.

Note that I'm *hoping* that if I can get a connection established between the client and `ws://localhost:3305/websocket/`, the Java code won't need to handle any of the Websocket messages between them.

Here's the controller code so far, based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/23736527/7376471:

```
private static final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(
    /* specific HttpRequestFactory here */);

@RequestMapping(path = "/shiny-proxy/**")
public ResponseEntity<String> mirrorRest(@RequestBody(required = false) String body,
        HttpMethod method, HttpServletRequest request) throws URISyntaxException {
    String path = StringUtils.removeStart(request.getRequestURI(), "/project/shiny-proxy");
    boolean websocket = false;
    URI uri;
    if (path.endsWith("/websocket/")) {
        websocket = true;
        // restore the ws:// that the request URL started with after Spring MVC makes it http://
        uri = new URI("ws", null, "localhost", 3305, path, request.getQueryString(), null);
    } else {
        uri = new URI(request.getScheme(), null, "localhost", 3305, path, request.getQueryString(), null);
    }
    if (websocket) {
        System.out.println(request.getRequestURL().toString());
        System.out.println(request.getRequestURI());
        System.out.println(path);
        System.out.println(uri);
    }

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    if (path.endsWith(".css.map")) { // special handling for unusual content types from Shiny
        headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    }
    HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);
    ResponseEntity<String> ret = null;
    try {
        ret = restTemplate.exchange(uri, method, httpEntity, String.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(request.getRequestURL().toString());
        System.out.println(request.getRequestURI());
        System.out.println(path);
        System.out.println(uri);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (websocket) {
        System.out.println("ResponseEntity headers: " + ret.getHeaders());
    }
    return ret;
}
```

but I can't find any `HttpRequestFactory` that works with `ws://` URLs (many of them convert URI's to java.net.URLs, which don't support ws://, and the others I've tested fail to handle ws:// in the reflective code) and even if I could, I'm not sure that returning a `ResponseEntity` would even work for ws connections.

So my question is, is there ANY way to get the controller to correctly establish a websocket connection between client and localhost:3305 given a ws:// request URL, or should I abandon the RestTemplate idea and try a configured proxy like Nginx instead?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out the solution using a configured proxy in my case was incredibly simple:
enable `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` in `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf`,

and set httpd-vhosts.conf's content to:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule /project/shiny-proxy/websocket/(.*) ws://localhost:3305/websocket/$1 [P,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Bitnami's default configuration is so good that no other changes were needed.