# Rest Template accept headers

Tags: resttemplate

I tried setting the Accept header as **application/json** and during service invocation i could see "**DEBUG o.s.web.client.RestTemplate** - Setting request Accept header to [text/plain, */*]" written in logs. Is my accept header overwritten ? how to restrict?

Code snippet:

```
    RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        requestHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON);
        requestHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, APPLICATION_JSON);
String url = "http://*******"
HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(requestBody, requestHeaders);
HttpEntity<String> response = template.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class);
```

Logs:

```
{Content-Type=[application/json], Accept=[application/json]}

13:08:06.091 [main] DEBUG o.s.web.client.RestTemplate - Created POST request for "http://********"
13:08:06.097 [main] DEBUG o.s.web.client.RestTemplate - Setting request Accept header to [text/plain, */*]
```

Comment: Solution here [How to set an “Accept:” header on Spring RestTemplate request?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19238715/how-to-set-an-accept-header-on-spring-resttemplate-request