# Add a header to RestTemplate using @Before advice

Tags: java, spring, http, aop, resttemplate

I'm having trouble adding a custom `Header` to a `RestTemplate` using AOP in Spring. 
What I have in mind is having some advice that will automatically modify execution of `RestTemplate.execute(..)` by adding this one Header. Other concern is targeting a particular `RestTemplate` instance that is a member of a `Service` which requires having this Header passed.

Here is the code of my Advice as it looks like now:

```
package com.my.app.web.controller.helper;

import com.my.app.web.HeaderContext;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.client.RequestCallback;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@Aspect
public class MyAppHeaderAspect {

  private static final String HEADER_NAME = "X-Header-Name";

  @Autowired
  HeaderContext headerContext;

  @Before("withinServiceApiPointcut() && executionOfRestTemplateExecuteMethodPointcut()")
  public void addHeader(RequestCallback requestCallback){
    if(requestCallback != null){
      String header = headerContext.getHeader();
    }
  }

  @Pointcut("within (com.my.app.service.NeedsHeaderService)")
  public void withinServiceApiPointcut() {}

  @Pointcut("execution (* org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(..)) && args(requestCallback)")
  public void executionOfRestTemplateExecuteMethodPointcut(RequestCallback requestCallback) {}
}
```

The problem that I'm having is how to modify RequestCallback to add my header. Being an interface it looks rather empty, on the other hand I'd rather not use a concrete implemntation because then I'd have to manually check if the implementation matches expected class. I'm beginning to wonder if this is really a correct method to do this. I found this answer [Add my custom http header to Spring RestTemplate request / extend RestTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32623407/add-my-custom-http-header-to-spring-resttemplate-request-extend-resttemplate/32623548)
But it uses `RestTemplate.exchange()` when I've checked that on my execution path `RestTemplate.execute()` is being used. Anyone has any ideas here?

Comment: Why? Just use a `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` for this instead of AOP and use a custom `RestTemplate` for that specific service.

Comment: And here is an excellent post showing what M. Deinum suggested: http://springinpractice.com/2013/10/27/how-to-send-an-http-header-with-every-request-with-spring-resttemplate

Comment: I dont think this may be possible for me. The `RestTemplate` I need to change is a member of the `ApiService`. Both classes arrive to me inside a library and I should interact with `RestTemplate` only through service's API.