# httpclienterror during get request for resttemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot

I keep getting the below exception when I try to do a `GET` request. A direct curl request to the url works fine but this doesn't. I'm trying to call service on port `8085` from the service on port `8082`.

Code

```
ResponseEntity<List<String>> quoteResponse = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8085/rest/test/{username}", HttpMethod.GET,
        null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>>() {
        },userName);
```

Curl

```
curl 'http://localhost:8082/rest/test/user1' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Error

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$NotFound: 404 : [<Map><timestamp>2020-06-18T23:35:31.449+00:00</timestamp><status>404</status><error>Not Found</error><message></message><path>/rest/test/user1</path></Map>]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:113) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:184) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:125) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
```

Comment: The port in the curl (8082) is different to the port in the code snippet (8085).
Also, just FYI - ur not sending the content-type header in the java code snippet as well - but the port is "likely" to the problem since ur getting a 404.
This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32623407/add-my-custom-http-header-to-spring-resttemplate-request-extend-resttemplate?lq=1 should help u to add the header.

Comment: Like i said, im trying to call the service on port 8085 from the service on port 8082

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be with the ports `8081` worked fine. So there seems to be some connectivity issue between `8082` and `8085`. Very Strange for me.

Answer (score 0):

where is your request header "Content-Type: application/json"

```java
HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
HttpEntity<JSONObject> req = new HttpEntity<>(new HashMap(), httpHeaders);
ResponseEntity<List<String>> quoteResponse = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8085/rest/test/{username}", HttpMethod.GET,
        req, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>>() {
        },userName);
```