# Spring Boot - configuring restTemplate for content-type application/json

Tags: json, spring-boot, content-type, resttemplate

I am trying to consume RESTful Web Service using this tutorial:
[Consuming a RESTful Web Service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/)

however when calling restTemplate I get following error

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class [cukamart.cvut.fel.cz.dto.Flight;] and content type [text/html;charset=UTF-8]
```

I don't understand why the content-type is set to **text/html**. It should be **application/json** since I added **jackson** dependency to my pom.xml and spring-boot should configure it for me right ?

> Because the Jackson JSON processing library is in the classpath, RestTemplate will use it (via a message converter) to convert the incoming JSON data

Here's my restTemplate bean

```
@Configuration
public class AosClientConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        return builder.build();
    }
}
```

pom.xml with jackson dependency

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>cukamart.cvut.fel.cz</groupId>
    <artifactId>aosclient</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>aosclient</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Controller which tries to consume RESTful Web Service

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/flight")
public class FlightController {

    @Value("${endpoint.url}")
    private String url;

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @GetMapping(value = "/preview")
    public String showAllFlights() {

        restTemplate.getForObject(url,  Flight[].class); //throw exception

        ....
        return "flights";
    }
}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong or how to tell restTemplate to use content-type application/json ?

I also tried this but I get the same error

```
@GetMapping(value = "/preview")
    public String showAllFlights() {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters", headers);

        restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Flight[].class);

        return "flights";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the "Content-Type" header in the response is not set. Can you send request to that URL using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/introduction)(Chrome Extension) or a similar REST client? That will help you see if the REST endpoint is actually returning data with the "Content-Type: application/json" response header.

http://blog.getpostman.com/2015/06/13/debugging-postman-requests/ explains how you can check for the response headers using Postman.

Comment: Thanks but I've already tried to request via advanced rest client and I get back response in json as well as in xml. I am also author of the server side and I've set - produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE}

Comment: If you are producing both json and/or xml type of responses, you should also pass an "Accept: application/json" header in the request to make sure you get the right response format. Here is an example of how to do that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19238715/how-to-set-an-accept-header-on-spring-resttemplate-request

Comment: I already tried it (see my question - last snippet) however I don't unserstand this line HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters", headers); What's "parameters" ?

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem might be with this line:

```
restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Flight[].class);
```

when the httpmethod is GET, it appears resttemplate ignores the body so your entity will not be included. change the httpmethod to POST and see if the target service receives a payload. if you control it, you might have to make changes to the target service for it to accept POST.