# Spring Boot Rest template returns null response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am getting json data from an api. The api is working well when passing it through browser or postman, but there is a null response. As json is quite complicated I stringify it. My code is below:

```
 String uri="api url";

 RestTemplate restTemplate1 = new RestTemplate();
 String result = restTemplate1.getForObject(uri, String.class);
 System.out.println(result);//result is null
 String jsonFormattedString = result.replaceAll("\\\\", "");//this throws null pointer exception
```

Comment: Please add some CURL or postman configuration which represents your http request when it runs successfully. You definitely miss some header, parameter, or smth. else.

Comment: Check if your `String uri` is actually pointing to a proper endpoint.

Comment: What is the http response code? You could change the getForObject call to the below to print out the response code:

ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate1.getForEntity(uri, String.class);
System.out.println(response.getStatusCode());
String result = response.getBody();

Comment: First of all test your rest endpoint if you can consult it via postman or other rest client, else maybe your rest return a null !

Comment: You might just need to add an `Accept: application/json` header. Have a look at something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19238715/how-to-set-an-accept-header-on-spring-resttemplate-request/19239013 for how to set it.