# Calling multiple external APIs in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, api

I am working on a project but it requires me to call multiple external APIs. I basically have to call an API to get a player id by giving a name. Then use that player id to get a list of match ids. Then make calls for each match id to get details on each match. its alot and doesnt seem optimal but its the only way to do it.  I was going to use rest template to make a call to the following

https://americas.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v5/matches/by-puuid/HDzjdaStxhHcceGGd8qJcc4Vw45FOlOQ1PNXKQ0h9_iqfwHP3oI0spl1bLUOw_7_J49vzaIKylv5Vg/ids?start=0&count=20

I have to pass in headers as well such as

riot token : token
"Origin": "https://developer.riotgames.com"

I was wondering how I can do this in Java Spring boot. I saw RestTemplate would be used but I couldnt figure out how to include the headers. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `RestTemplate.exchange()` using either the method signature with [RequestEntity](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/RequestEntity.java) or with [HttpEntity](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/HttpEntity.java).

```java
// Using RequestEntity
RequestEntity<?> request= RequestEntity.get(url).header(headerName, headerValue).build();
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(request, String.class);

// Using HttpEntity
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set(headerName, headerValue);
HttpEntity httpEntity = new HttpEntity(/* this is nullable */ requestBody, headers);
ResponseEntity,String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, String.class);
```

Would also recommend reading through the following:

- https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/resttemplate/spring-restful-client-resttemplate-example/
- https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template
- [How to set an "Accept:" header on Spring RestTemplate request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19238715/how-to-set-an-accept-header-on-spring-resttemplate-request)